# PHPUnit tests on functions in file

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm trying to set up PHPUnit on PhpStorm 8 to test a file with some functions inside it. I have it set up with composer and a structure like this:

```
/src/functions.php
/test/functionsTest.php
/vendor/phpunit...
/composer.json
```

`functions.php` includes just a few functions like:

```
function add_one ($x) {

    return $x++;

}
```

And `functionsTest.php` has something like:

```
class functionsTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function test_map () {

        $this->assertEquals(2, add_one(1));

    }

}
```

I've got PhpStorm configured to use the phpunit from the project `/vendor` and a PHP executable elsewhere. However, running this I just get `call to undefined function add_one()`. I set my phpunit.xml configuration file to contain:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Functions Test">
        <directory>./test/</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>

<filter>
    <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="false">
        <directory suffix=".php">./src/</directory>
        <exclude>
            <directory suffix=".php">vendor</directory>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

The bootstrap `phpunit.php` is set to require the composer autoload (so a one-liner). I've been reading the PHPUnit documentation all day and just cannot see how I'm not getting it to work out.

Comment: You're sure that include the file function in your unit test?

Comment: I need to include the functions.php file? I didn't know if there were autoload magic I need to do; for best practices.

Comment: You're used php functional, the best practice are that use OOP :), and the millon question you have a autoload configured?, if you see the autoload (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) is based in class, and the good practices about of phpunit are here(https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html)

Comment: Thanks! Yes I typically use OOP, but in this case I'm playing with just functions not wrapped in a class and I wanted to still have it testable. I'll just use the include unless there's a better way. Thanks!